# Xcode changing constraints dependant on screen orientation

Tags: xcode, ipad, autolayout

I have designed an app using auto layout and all works perfectly, issue is, when I switch to landscape I want the location of one button to move to the other side of the screen.

Im assuming the best way of doing this is by changing the constraints when I rotate the screen, is this possible in the code, or even the best way of doing it? Obviously if the app starts up in landscape I obviously want this button to be in the landscape mode also.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. Remove and add constraints as desired in your view controller's `updateViewConstraints` implementation.

You will find it easiest to prepare both sets of alternate constraints beforehand, maintaining them in instance variables. Then you can just swap them in and out. Here's a sketch of what the code could look like:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.oneSideConstraints];
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.otherSideConstraints];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        [self.view addConstraints:self.oneSideConstraints];
    else
        [self.view addConstraints:self.otherSideConstraints];
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

Comment: Here's an actual example, from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p255rotationChangesInterface/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.m You can download and run that example and you'll see it is doing almost exactly the sort of thing you are after.